# Swift UI shimmer modifier no longer works on iOS 17

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've been using the same shimmer modifier for a while now. I just recently updated to the new iOS and the shimmer modifier no longer works. I made sure nothing in my code was depreciated. I'm not certain as to why it no longer functions, I assume it is due to new updates in the way iOS animates things.

```
import SwiftUI

public struct Shimmer: ViewModifier {
    let animation: Animation
    @State private var phase: CGFloat = 0

    public init(animation: Animation = Self.defaultAnimation) {
        self.animation = animation
    }

    public static let defaultAnimation = Animation.linear(duration: 1.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)

    public init(duration: Double = 1.5, bounce: Bool = false, delay: Double = 0) {
        self.animation = .linear(duration: duration)
            .repeatForever(autoreverses: bounce)
            .delay(delay)
    }

    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .modifier(
                AnimatedMask(phase: phase).animation(animation)
            )
            .onAppear { phase = 0.8 }
    }

    struct AnimatedMask: AnimatableModifier {
        var phase: CGFloat = 0

        var animatableData: CGFloat {
            get { phase }
            set { phase = newValue }
        }

        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            content
                .mask(GradientMask(phase: phase).scaleEffect(4))
        }
    }

    struct GradientMask: View {
        let phase: CGFloat
        let centerColor = Color.black
        let edgeColor = Color.black.opacity(0.3)
        @Environment(\.layoutDirection) private var layoutDirection

        var body: some View {
            let isRightToLeft = layoutDirection == .rightToLeft
            LinearGradient(
                gradient: Gradient(stops: [
                    .init(color: edgeColor, location: phase),
                    .init(color: centerColor, location: phase + 0.1),
                    .init(color: edgeColor, location: phase + 0.2)
                ]),
                startPoint: isRightToLeft ? .bottomTrailing : .topLeading,
                endPoint: isRightToLeft ? .topLeading : .bottomTrailing
            )
        }
    }
}

public extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func shimmering(
        active: Bool = true, duration: Double = 1.5, bounce: Bool = false, delay: Double = 0
    ) -> some View {
        if active {
            self.modifier(Shimmer(duration: duration, bounce: bounce, delay: delay))
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder func shimmering(active: Bool = true, animation: Animation = Shimmer.defaultAnimation) -> some View {
        if active {
            self.modifier(Shimmer(animation: animation))
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use a spell-checker when posting here. Moreover, when edits are made to your posts, it's worth remembering those kinds of edits, so they do not need to be made again on your new material. Questions asked on Stack Overflow are for future engineers, not just the people who post them. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AnimatableModifier` is deprecated. This doesn't need the `AnimatableMask`. You can animate the mask just by using the `animation` modifier that takes a `value:` parameter

```
// Shimmer.body
public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
        .mask(
            GradientMask(phase: phase).scaleEffect(3)
        )
        .animation(animation, value: phase)
        .onAppear { phase = 0.8 }
}
```

That said, I'm not sure why `scaleEffect(3)` or how the logic for the gradient stops work. `scaleEffect(3)` just makes the whole gradient *extremely* large, and you can't really see the animation well at all. If you remove `scaleEffect`, the animation doesn't look that good either.

Perhaps how gradient stops work changed at some point.

I assume [this](https://github.com/markiv/SwiftUI-Shimmer/blob/main/Sources/Shimmer/Shimmer.swift) is where you got the code from. Looking at that repo's history, the author changed from animating stops to animating the start and end points of the gradient, which makes a lot more sense to me, and actually looks quite nice.

Here is the code:

```
public struct Shimmer: ViewModifier {
    private let animation: Animation
    private let gradient: Gradient
    private let min, max: CGFloat
    @State private var isInitialState = true
    @Environment(\.layoutDirection) private var layoutDirection

    /// Initializes his modifier with a custom animation,
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - animation: A custom animation. Defaults to ``Shimmer/defaultAnimation``.
    ///   - gradient: A custom gradient. Defaults to ``Shimmer/defaultGradient``.
    ///   - bandSize: The size of the animated mask's "band". Defaults to 0.3 unit points, which corresponds to
    /// 30% of the extent of the gradient.
    public init(
        animation: Animation = Self.defaultAnimation,
        gradient: Gradient = Self.defaultGradient,
        bandSize: CGFloat = 0.3
    ) {
        self.animation = animation
        self.gradient = gradient
        // Calculate unit point dimensions beyond the gradient's edges by the band size
        self.min = 0 - bandSize
        self.max = 1 + bandSize
    }

    /// The default animation effect.
    public static let defaultAnimation = Animation.linear(duration: 1.5).delay(0.25).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)

    // A default gradient for the animated mask.
    public static let defaultGradient = Gradient(colors: [
        .black.opacity(0.3), // translucent
        .black, // opaque
        .black.opacity(0.3) // translucent
    ])

    /*
     Calculating the gradient's animated start and end unit points:
     min,min
        \
         ┌───────┐         ┌───────┐
         │0,0    │ Animate │       │  "forward" gradient
     LTR │       │ ───────►│    1,1│  / // /
         └───────┘         └───────┘
                                    \
                                  max,max
                max,min
                  /
         ┌───────┐         ┌───────┐
         │    1,0│ Animate │       │  "backward" gradient
     RTL │       │ ───────►│0,1    │  \ \\ \
         └───────┘         └───────┘
                          /
                       min,max
     */

    /// The start unit point of our gradient, adjusting for layout direction.
    var startPoint: UnitPoint {
        if layoutDirection == .rightToLeft {
            return isInitialState ? UnitPoint(x: max, y: min) : UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        } else {
            return isInitialState ? UnitPoint(x: min, y: min) : UnitPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
        }
    }

    /// The end unit point of our gradient, adjusting for layout direction.
    var endPoint: UnitPoint {
        if layoutDirection == .rightToLeft {
            return isInitialState ? UnitPoint(x: 1, y: 0) : UnitPoint(x: min, y: max)
        } else {
            return isInitialState ? UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 0) : UnitPoint(x: max, y: max)
        }
    }

    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .mask(LinearGradient(gradient: gradient, startPoint: startPoint, endPoint: endPoint))
            .animation(animation, value: isInitialState)
            .onAppear {
                isInitialState = false
            }
    }
}

public extension View {
    /// Adds an animated shimmering effect to any view, typically to show that an operation is in progress.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - active: Convenience parameter to conditionally enable the effect. Defaults to `true`.
    ///   - animation: A custom animation. Defaults to ``Shimmer/defaultAnimation``.
    ///   - gradient: A custom gradient. Defaults to ``Shimmer/defaultGradient``.
    ///   - bandSize: The size of the animated mask's "band". Defaults to 0.3 unit points, which corresponds to
    /// 20% of the extent of the gradient.
    @ViewBuilder func shimmering(
        active: Bool = true,
        animation: Animation = Shimmer.defaultAnimation,
        gradient: Gradient = Shimmer.defaultGradient,
        bandSize: CGFloat = 0.3
    ) -> some View {
        if active {
            modifier(Shimmer(animation: animation, gradient: gradient, bandSize: bandSize))
        } else {
            self
        }
    }

    /// Adds an animated shimmering effect to any view, typically to show that an operation is in progress.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - active: Convenience parameter to conditionally enable the effect. Defaults to `true`.
    ///   - duration: The duration of a shimmer cycle in seconds.
    ///   - bounce: Whether to bounce (reverse) the animation back and forth. Defaults to `false`.
    ///   - delay:A delay in seconds. Defaults to `0.25`.
    @available(*, deprecated, message: "Use shimmering(active:animation:gradient:bandSize:) instead.")
    @ViewBuilder func shimmering(
        active: Bool = true, duration: Double, bounce: Bool = false, delay: Double = 0.25
    ) -> some View {
        shimmering(
            active: active,
            animation: .linear(duration: duration).delay(delay).repeatForever(autoreverses: bounce)
        )
    }
}
```